# Firebase Data not showing in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So basically I want to get the data from Firebase and put it in the tableView and then when a cell is deleted I want to remove the data from firebase and the table view...but with my code the data is NOT even showing up in the TableView and i really don't know what's wrong...?

Here's my Database structure if it helps:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQRR5.png)

I put the data in Courses then a childByAutoId which contains CourseName,AmountOfHoles and AddedDate then get it back in a snapshot, store the snapshot in an array called courses and then get the variables for the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath but somehow the cell is not showing on the tableView...then I would delete the cell and data in commitEditingStyle but it doesn't even get to that because the cells don't show up...

I'm new to StackOverflow, so please excuse me if something seems stupid or wrong ...dont bother to tell me tho..

```
class CoursesViewController: UITableViewController {

  var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()
  override func viewDidLoad() {

  ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

  tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false


  //let a = ref.childByAutoId()
  //a.setValue("hi")

  }

  var courses: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)

  let CoursesRef = ref.child("Courses")

  CoursesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshpt in

  self.courses.append(snapshpt)


  })


  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return self.courses.count
  }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
  UITableViewCell {

  let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


  let courseSnap: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.courses[indexPath.row]

  let course = courseSnap.value

  let coursename = course?.objectForKey("CourseName") as! String
  let amountofholes = course?.objectForKey("AmountOfHoles") as! String
  let addeddate = course?.objectForKey("AddedDate") as! String

  cell.textLabel?.text = coursename + " " + amountofholes + " Holes"
  cell.detailTextLabel?.text = addeddate

  return cell

  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
  return true
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .Delete {

  // Find the snapshot and remove the value
  let courseitem = courses[indexPath.row]

  courseitem.ref.removeValue()


  }
  }

  @IBAction func addButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {


  // Alert View for input

  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Course Item",message: "Add Course",preferredStyle: .Alert)

  let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

  //Get Date String
  let date = NSDate()
  print(date)

  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy 'at' HH:mm"
  let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
  print(dateString)
  //
  let courseField = alert.textFields![0]
  let holesField = alert.textFields![1]





  let Courses = self.ref.child("Courses").childByAutoId()

  let course = ["AddedDate": dateString as AnyObject,
  "CourseName": courseField.text as! AnyObject,
  "AmountOfHoles": holesField.text as! AnyObject]

  Courses.setValue(course)


  }


  //Cancel
  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
  }

  //TextField placeholder in alert
  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
  (courseField: UITextField!) -> Void in

  courseField.placeholder = "Course Name"
  }
  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
  (holesField: UITextField!) -> Void in

  holesField.placeholder = "Holes (6/9/18)"
  }

  //Add alert
  alert.addAction(saveAction)
  alert.addAction(cancelAction)

  presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }


}
```

Comment: reload your tableview ...

Comment: wow i feel stupid now...thank you...that works but now if i change the view and go back again the cell duplicates...and the if i delete it it doesn't go away..?

Comment: add your viewDidAppear code in viewDidLoad and check

Comment: that works...now they don't duplicate but still if i delete them they don't go away in the tableview but they do in firebase

Comment: nope it doesn't go away stay right there in the tableview

Comment: ohhh ... you need to delete that object from your array too and than reload data and check

Comment: ohh i see thanks now it works..sorry i was so frustrated that i didn't see the easy stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man you have to insert your code when a snapshot is found out !

I think you can go like this :

```
CoursesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
  self.courses.append(snapshot)
  self.yourTable.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.courses.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
          })
```

Comment: ..I solved it by reloading the table view and putting the observeventtype in viewdidload()...but i found this somewhere and it woks to thanks

Answer (score 0):

check with this code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if(self.courses.count > 0){
 tablecount = self.courses.count
} else {

 tablecount = 0
 self.table.reloaddata()
}
return tablecount
}
```